# Two timestamps in dockerlogs

Tags: docker, logging

Docker system with logging driver set to json-file.

I start my container with a TZ environment variable to set my app's time zone. However, the logs are generated with two timestamps. One in the "**log**" field is set by the application (it seems), and that's correct. Another timestamp is added in a "**time**" field and that is set to UTC. Any idea how to set the time zone in the "**time**" field?

```
{"log":"[2021-10-26T10:25:16+02:00] @DEBUG Ita singillatim piae gaudium falsissime habitaret fama. 3483 ::0.547919\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-26T08:25:16.251790686Z"}
{"log":"[2021-10-26T10:25:17+02:00] @INFO Inveniret cura aut, grave miseros. 3484 ::0.286877\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-26T08:25:17.252317279Z"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker timestamps it's logs in UTC by default. I don't think there is a option to change this.

https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/604

It is a best practice to log in UTC and then convert to the whichever TZ is required.